# jQuery Autocomplete with C# and SQL Server Database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, dynamic, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to use jQuery autocomplete on my dynamically created textboxes. this is my first time working with jQuery so I am not so sure about where I am getting off...
My ASMX page code is working fine & generating result as asked but my javascript of
autocomplete is not calling the page at all (tried in debug) and its not giving me error
message either... Help Please!!

EDIT :
      I am still having error "ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load."

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=dRAn80ZulnXIbHUFZAi0thqEaFFdeMlwAh6uA_ciIINTs7jTUe13ADvaDyjOl6tPSr-1TN4Bqt6MFVjznyiXABGNxDhFk5_-02EGxOku0B-Tim4ebG59zhvC6DdsHV11uoIY024U1o0IMngrTBO45x9tPeG-PiyEUPEypUFf795T-3SY0&amp;t=ffffffffb868b5f4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
```

Upon typing in the textbox, I get the pop up error :

Ajax error: researcher_list.asmx/FetchResList : error : undefined : Internal Server Error : 500

**EDITED CODE :**

Aspx Code :

```
$(function() {
    $('input:text').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var pString = '{ "resName": "' + request.term + '" }';
            $.ajax({
                url: "researcher_list.asmx/FetchResList", /* same root as the page? */
                data: pString,
                dataType: "jsond",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json", /* simplify */
                converters: {/* avoid the d or no d issue, works with 3.5 or prior this way */
                    "json jsond": function(msg) {
                        return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
                    }
                },
                success: function(data) {/* assumes data always returned and it IS called item in the JSON */
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.name,
                            label: item.name
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + this.url + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown + " : " + xhr.statusText + " : " + xhr.status;

                    if (xhr.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort") {
                        alert(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

Asmx Code :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/v2/pages/main.aspx")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class researcher_list : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public List<DBResearcher.Summary> FetchResList(string resName)
    {
        //SqlConnection connection;
        //SqlCommand command = null;
        //SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        //string sql;
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var tempSum = new DBResearcher();
        var allRes = DBResearcher.GetAllResearcher()
                        .Where(m => m.name.ToLower().Contains(resName.ToLower()));
        return allRes.ToList();
    }

    public static string[] GetCustomerNames()
    {
        string[] data = new string[] { "Andrew", "Ramona", "Russ", "Russell",  Raymond" };

        return data;

    }
}
```

web.config file :

```
<httpHandlers>
  <!-- AJAX.Net Configuration -->
  <add verb="GET,POST" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax"/>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpHandlers>

<!-- HTTP MODULES -->

 <httpModules>
  <!-- doesn't work if we restrict it by <location path=...> for some reason,
            so we have no choice but to do this at the root level. -->
  <!--<add name="HttpUploadModule" type="AssistedSolutions.SlickUpload.HttpUploadModule, AssistedSolutions.SlickUpload" />
    -->
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

 </httpModules>
```

EDIT - 
Error while running asmx page on its own

```
Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to Execute URL.]
   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProcForIIS6.BeginExecuteUrl(String url, String method, String childHeaders, Boolean sendHeaders, Boolean addUserIndo, IntPtr token, String name, String authType, Byte[] entity, AsyncCallback cb, Object state) +2008569
   System.Web.HttpResponse.BeginExecuteUrlForEntireResponse(String pathOverride, NameValueCollection requestHeaders, AsyncCallback cb, Object state) +393
   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +220
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8699714
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: try to change data: `"{ 'mail': '" + request.term + "' }",` to  `data: '{ "resName": "' + request.term + '" }', `

Comment: No change.. Its still the same. The ASMX file is still not being called.

Comment: Note the difference in quotes as well as name being passed.

Comment: No I meant no change in the result...even after changing the quotes & name, its still not working...
I know I am doing something very stupid.. just cant figure that stupid thing out

Comment: You put the missing curly brace in as noted by Troy?

Comment: nope, adding that bracket does nothing but there is a curly bracket at the end the same line. Does that count for the missing bracket? The same code in the other testing project (which is slightly different) works.

Comment: No, that bracket at the end is for the source: function. autoComplete expects an object to be passed such as in the documentation for source at: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote or in the example that Troy presents.

Comment: Yeah.. checked that out.. And then ran the debugger... I thought that the problem was in that script but this is the first problem..
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw...nt-side framework failed to load.');

Comment: Are you missing double quote in: `public static string[] GetCustomerNames() { string[] data = new string[] { "Andrew", "Ramona", "Russ", "Russell", Raymond" };` just before the last name in the list?

Comment: You should be able to put in `http://localhost/mycorrectpath/researcher_list.asmx` (or whatever path needs to be after the localhost prior to the researcher_list really) and see the method listed in your browser on your development machine.

Comment: Interesting... When i try to run it, it lets me run FetchResList but When I entered value & clicked submit, it gave me an error -
URL - http://localhost/v2/pages/researcher_list.asmx/FetchResList
ERROR - 
Failed to Execute URL.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Failed to Execute URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is built based on an asp.net 3.5 solution and jQuery 1.7.1 version assumption.  Much has been already covered by other posters.  Yours may vary by version.  This is simply an attempt to put comments in an answer with a completed script and server side notes.

Have you decorated your class thus:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mysite.com/researcher_list/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class researcher_list : WebService
{
```

Decorate your method: (use the EnableSession IF you need that...)

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public List<DBResearcher.Summary> FetchResList(string resName)        {
```

cleanup of the client script:

```
$('input:text').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var pString = '{ "resName": "' + request.term + '" }';
        $.ajax({
            url: "researcher_list.asmx/FetchResList",
            /* same root as the page? */
            data: pString,
            dataType: "jsond",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            /* simplify */
            converters: { /* avoid the d or no d issue, works with 3.5 or prior this way */
                "json jsond": function(msg) {
                    return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
                }
            },
            success: function(data) { /* assumes data always returned and it IS called item in the JSON */
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.name,
                        label: item.name
                    };
                }));
            },
            minLength: 2,
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + this.url + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown + " : " + xhr.statusText + " : " + xhr.status;
                if (xhr.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort") {
                    alert(errorMessage);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

IN ADDITION to the above, there are Web.config settings in asp.net that need set to get a web service to function - assumption here is you have done the research and have that working.  IF NOT, suggestion is create a simple method that returns the current time as a string with NO parameters (data:"{}",) and get that via ajax to ensure it works before the complexity of the autocomplete is layered.

Comment: I checked config file many times.. Everything seems to be in the order.. The script above is giving me the missing bracket error. I added the missing bracket but its still there. May be I am messing on syntax?
P.S. - The asmx file is already decorated

Comment: I got the missing bracket error.. I ended up putting a semi-colon with it thinking its from one level above...
but the error if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.'); is still there though... which in turn I believe, gives this error "Ajax error: researcher_list.asmx/FetchResList : error : undefined : Internal Server Error : 500"

Comment: I ran the script snippet through jslint and fixed a couple of minor issues with my typing.

Answer (score 1):

Try marking your method with a WebMethod attribute like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<DBResearcher.Summary> FetchResList(string mail)
{
...
}
```

Also, your parameters will need to match, so change resName to mail.

You can also merge your jQuery each into the autocomplete selector:

```
$('input:text').autocomplete(...)
```

Edit:

Try this code:

```
$('input:text').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "researcher_list.asmx/FetchResList",
            data: "{ 'resName': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }, minLength: 2
});
```

Comment: it is a webmethod, i just didnt include that code..also if i use static javascript array, it is working for every dynamic box.. 
My problem is that the script is not calling the asmx file

Comment: You need a { before the "source". Are you noticing any syntax errors in debugger?

Comment: I think the one you are talking about is after source: function(request, response)

Comment: @Troy, nice catch on the missing curly brace before the source